# Typedef and function declaration

Tags: c++, typedef

I'm trying to write:

```
typedef int foo();
...
foo bar
{
    return 1;
}
```

But I have `error C2206`, that typedef cannot be using for function declaration. What causes this error? I think `foo bar` should just compile as `int bar()`.

Comment: Function types aren't object types. You can't "declare a variable of function type". You can only "declare a function". That's just how the language is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declaration:

```
typedef int foo();
```

is perfectly valid. It defines `foo` as an alias for the type `int()`, or "function returning `int` and taking no arguments".

(An aside: C uses `(void)` to indicate no arguments; C++ uses `()`. An earlier version of this answer was based on C rules.)

It's more common to define typedefs for pointer-to-function types rather than for function types, but both are valid.  Given the above typedef, you could declare a function pointer object as:

```
foo *funcptr;
```

But you can't declare or define a function using a typedef. If the language permitted it, you could declare a function as:

```
foo func; /* would be equivalent to "int func(void);" *if* it were legal */
```

or:

```
foo func { return 42; }; /* would be equivalent to 
                            "int func(void) { return 42; }"
                            *if* it were legal */
```

There are even times when this would be convenient. The standard `signal` function, defined in `<signal.h>` or `<csignal>`, has a fairly complicated declaration:

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

You can define a `typedef` for the function type of a signal handler:

```
typedef void (signal_handler)(int);
```

would would allow `signal` to be declared as:

```
void (*signal(int sig, signal_handler *func);
```

but you can't use that typedef to declare or define your own signal handler -- though you can usefully use it to declare *pointers* to signal handler functions:

```
signal_handler *funcptr = my_handler;
signal(SIGINT, funcptr);
```

The same applies to the function pointer arguments required by `qsort()` and `bsearch()`.

So given that you can define a typedef for a function type, why can't you use it to declare or define a function?

I don't think there's any deep reason. The language just doesn't happen to permit it. For function declarations, one problem is that

```
signal_handler foo;
```

looks just like an object declaration, but it would instead declare a function (that must be defined elsewhere). And permitting typedefs for function *definitions*:

```
signal_handler foo { /* ... */ }
```

would require a change to the language grammar -- and would make it difficult to see the parameter and return types when looking at the definition. Also, function definitions, unlike declarations, require names for any parameters, which would add another level of complexity.

But the real reason, I think, is that Dennis Ritchie, when he designed C, either didn't think of it, or didn't think it was worthwhile (and Stroustrup didn't have a good enough reason to change that when he designed C++).

Comment: `typedef int foo(); foo func; int bar() { return sizeof(decltype(func())); }` seems to be valid code such that `bar()` returns 4. What am I missing here?

Comment: `foo func;` *declares* but does not *define* a function named `func`. The argument of `sizeof` is not evaluated, so there's no attempt to call that function. If you add a call `func()` you'll get a link-time error which can be resolved by providing a definition of `func` -- but that definition can't use the typedef.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration for a function pointer typedef is

```
typedef int (*foo)();
```

Also you are missing parens in your function declaration

```
foo bar()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Also `1` is not a legal function pointer value.

```
foo bar()
{
    return 1;  // this line is an error
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, it's typo. Corrected.

Comment: @john I think OP wants `bar` to be of type `foo`, not *return* type `foo`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Hmm, ok you're probably right, in that case it's just `int bar() { return 1; }`, no need to involve foo at all.